# Proper way to display "Code" sections in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there a "best way". Something that sort of makes the portion of code look inset?

For instance, how SO displays "code" sections on posts for example?

I know Bootstrap has "Wells" but when not using it, is there a particular way that is functional looks nice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tag `pre` or `code` for that kind of things.

```css
code { 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2)
}

pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2)
}
```

```html
The <code>&lt;code&gt;</code> tag.

<pre>
Here's a  &lt;pre&gt; tag. some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text 
</pre>
```